# Problema ao iniciar o mysql no xampp

Tags: mysql

eu tentei usar o xampp mas toda vez que eu tento iniciar o mysql acusa o seguinte erro:

```
Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MYSQL57"!
```

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Fecha o Skype, pode ser um chute, mas a maioria dos casos que vi foi exatamente ele usando a mesma porta xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você já tem o Mysql instalado no seu computador e rodando na porta `3306` por isso está dando conflito, pois o xampp está tentando iniciar seu Mysql nessa mesma porta, a solução é desinstalar o que já estava ou alterar a porta de um deles para `3307` por exemplo.

No xampp você pode alterar a porta do Mysql através da janela Xampp Control Panel.

[image: xampp control panel]

Na opção config do Mysql abrirá um arquivo de texto pra edição, encotre a porta `3306` e altere para outra qualquer. Após alterar salve e feche o arquivo, pare e inicie o serviço no xampp.

Answer (score -4):

Vou relatar meu erro ,
Tentei fazer o Xampp instalar e rodar mysql e Apache , porém descuidei de não observar que mesmo estes não rodando após startar , o Xampp já havia sido instalado em uma pasta .
Ao invés de só mudar o valor da porta para 3307 , eu voltava a baixar o Xampp novamente , fiz isto umas 4 vezes e só aumentava o conflito , então desinstalei tudo e comecei novamente .

1 instalei novamente após desinstalar as inst. anteriores

2 startei o Apache e ele rodou , sua porta era 3306

3 em config , ao lado de Admin mudei a porta para o Mysql para 3307

4 depois selecionei a pasta da instalação e confirmei.

problema resolvido

Comment: Isso não soluciona o problema do AP. O usuário já possui um instancia do MSQL instalada e rodando na porta 3306. No caso o xampp está tentando iniciar uma instancia do MariaDB na mesma porta 3306. Para resolver basta configurar o xampp para que não inicie instancia do MariaDB ou então encerrar a instancia do MySql quando levantar o xampp.